# Why my REST api created with camel servlet doesn't expose?

Tags: java, rest, servlets, apache-camel, integration

I'm currently struggling with exposing the REST api in my project using Apache Camel. When I run the project it seems to be fine in the console, but it just doesn't
work:

> curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/materials

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8080: Connection refused

Here's the pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>Packages</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jsonpath</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.28</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId >
        <version>2.17.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
        <version>5.16.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
        <version>5.16.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jaxb-starter</artifactId>
        <version>2.25.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
        <version>3.15.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-broker</artifactId>
        <version>5.16.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-xml-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-rest</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-RC3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-jackson-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-RC3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Here's the code I wrote:

```
package com.release11.output;

import com.release11.xjc.materials.ObjectFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent;
import org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestBindingMode;
import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;


public class OutputAdapter1 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://127.0.0.1:61616");

    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.start();

    CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
    context.addComponent("activemq", JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));

    context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
        JaxbDataFormat xmlDataFormat = new JaxbDataFormat(jaxbContext);
            xmlDataFormat.setIgnoreJAXBElement(false);

        restConfiguration()
                    .component("servlet")
                    .host("localhost")
                    .port("8080")
                    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);

        from("activemq:topic:MATERIALS_ENRICHED")
                    .unmarshal(xmlDataFormat)
                    .filter(simple("${body.type} in 'A1,A2,A3'"))
                .to("direct:materials");

        rest("/materials")
                    .get().route()
                    .to("direct:materials");
        }
    });
    context.start();
}
}
```

I'm not sure to put the build output here because it's quite long so I'll put only a fragment where those routes start:

> 12:47:22.591 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConsumer - Started listener container org.apache.camel.component.jms.DefaultJmsMessageListenerContainer@52045dbe on destination MATERIALS_ENRICHED
> 12:47:22.591 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager - Route: route1 started and consuming from: activemq://topic:MATERIALS_ENRICHED
> 12:47:22.593 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager - Route: route2 >>> Route[rest://get:/materials?consumerComponentName=servlet&routeId=route2 -> null]
> 12:47:22.593 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager - Starting consumer (order: 1001) on route: route2
> 12:47:22.593 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.support.DefaultConsumer - Build consumer: Consumer[servlet:/materials?httpMethodRestrict=GET]
> 12:47:22.593 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.support.DefaultConsumer - Init consumer: Consumer[servlet:/materials?httpMethodRestrict=GET]
> 12:47:22.593 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.support.DefaultConsumer - Starting consumer: Consumer[servlet:/materials?httpMethodRestrict=GET]
> 12:47:22.595 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpRegistry - Registering consumer for path /materials providers present: 0
> 12:47:22.595 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.engine.InternalRouteStartupManager - Route: route2 started and consuming from: servlet:/materials
> 12:47:22.597 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext - Routes startup summary (total:2 started:2)
> 12:47:22.597 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext -     Started route1 (activemq://topic:MATERIALS_ENRICHED)
> 12:47:22.597 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext -     Started route2 (rest://get:/materials)
> 12:47:22.597 [main] INFO org.apache.camel.impl.engine.AbstractCamelContext - Apache Camel 3.12.0 (camel-1) started in 525ms (build:81ms init:296ms start:148ms)
> 12:47:22.610 [main] DEBUG org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext - start() took 457 millis

Please inform me in the comments shall I put the full build output so I'll edit the ticket.
Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component `camel-servlet` is not meant to be used in standalone mode as you are trying to do. It is meant to be used when you deploy your Camel application on a Servlet container or an Application Server.

In standalone mode, if you want to expose a rest endpoint, you should rather use a component like `camel-undertow`, `camel-jetty`, `camel-netty-http` or `camel-platform-http` (you can find the full list [here](https://camel.apache.org/manual/rest-dsl.html#_components_supporting_rest_dsl)).

---

Assuming that you want to use `undertow`, you will have to follow the next steps

In your pom file you need to replace `camel-rest` with `camel-undertow`, as next:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-undertow</artifactId>
    <version>3.12.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, you just need to change your rest configuration to use `undertow` and it should be good:

```
restConfiguration()
    .component("undertow")
    .port(8080)
    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.auto);
```

Comment: I've changed it and now I get an error `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find RestApiProcessorFactory in Registry or classpath (such as the camel-openapi-java component)`. What shall I do?

Comment: It is obviously another problem that is not related to this one. Please create another question for it to avoid mixing problems